# Where is the general linear group in geometric algebra?

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras, general-linear-group

My question is about $\operatorname{CL}_4(\mathbb{R})$. Where do I find the general linear group in $\operatorname{CL}_4(\mathbb{R})$?

---

For example in $\operatorname{CL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, a general multivector is:

$$
\mathbf{v}=a+x e_1+y e_2+be_1e_2
$$

The matrix representation of $\mathbf{v}$ is

$$
V=\pmatrix{a+x&& b+y\\-b+y&&a-x}
$$

Since $V$ is in $\mathbb{M}(2,\mathbb{R})$ then it follows that the reversible multivectors are group isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

---

Since in two dimensions, it is simple, but in 4 dimensions the matrix representation of $\operatorname{CL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ are complex matrices with real determinants. So the correspondance is not identical.

Comment: Can you give the definition of $CL_n(K)$?

Comment: @Burde Yes, the clifford algebra of dimensions n over the field K. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra

Comment: The case $CL_4(\Bbb C)$ is discussed [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjn0rWq8u3sAhWF_qQKHa7QAvsQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-01826553%2Fdocument&usg=AOvVaw0GZ9NYqlYAiyP4FPDWRM87). The real case should go the same way. By the way, your title has "geometric algebra"?? Do you mean Clifford algebra?

Comment: @DietrichBurde According to the second answer https://www.quora.com/How-are-geometric-algebra-and-Clifford-algebra-different a geometric algebra is just a Clifford algebra over the reals? The complex case is trivial because $Cl_4(C)$ is a basis for $M(4,C)$. However, $Cl_4(R)$ is not a basis for $M(4,R)$, yet the determinant of the matrix representation of elements of $Cl_4(R)$ is real even if the matrix representation is complex. https://people.kth.se/~dogge/clifford/files/clifford.pdf page 91 the author state (without proof) that reversible multivectors form the general linear group.